# Creating numpy shallow copies with arithmetic operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, shallow-copy

I noticed that array operations with an identity elements return a copy (possibly a shallow copy) of the array.

Consider the code snippet below.

```py
a=np.arange(16).reshape([4,4])
print(a)
b=a+0
print(b)
a[2,2]=200
print(a)
print(b)
```

We see that `b` is a shallow copy of `a`. I don't know if it is a deep copy, because I think matrix is a subtype of array, rather than array of arrays.

If I only need a shallow copy,

- Is there a difference between using np.copy() and arithmetic operations?
- Is `b=a+0` or `b=a*1` a bad practice? If it is, why?

I know this is a frequently asked topic, but I couldn't find an answer for my particular question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't have assumed that `b = a + 0` won't be optimized to the equivalent of `b = a`. If you want a copy, be explicit.

Comment: @chepner Well, I thought so too, that is why I tested it out. It is a copy, not an assignment (or aliasing).

Comment: I mean, I wouldn't *continue* to assume that. Maybe a future version of NumPy *does* make that optimization (it has the information it needs to do so). `np.copy` at least makes it *obvious* that you are creating a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a difference between using np.copy() and arithmetic
> operations?

Yes, consider following example

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[True,False],[False,True]])
arr_c = np.copy(arr)
arr_0 = arr + 0
print(arr_c)
print(arr_0)
```

output

```
[[ True False]
 [False  True]]
[[1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

observe that both operations are legal (did not cause exception or error) yet give different results.

Comment: This answer my question perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

With `numpy` arrays there isn't a difference between shallow copy and deep copy - unless you are working with object dtype arrays (which practically speaking are lists).

There is an important distinction between `view` and `copy`.  In

```
 a=np.arange(16).reshape([4,4])
```

`a` is actually a view of the 1d array produced by `arange` (check `a.base`)

The `b=a` action is basic Python.  `b` is just another way to reference the same object.

`b=a[:]` is a view; a new array with a shared databuffer (same `arange` base).

`b=a.copy()`, and `b=a+0` are both new arrays without any sharing.  As long as you get the `dtypes` right, these are functionally the same.

`a+0` translates to `np.add(a,0)`.  `np.add.identity` is `0`, so as @chepner wrote, it does have the information to "optimize", but only to the equivalent of `copy`.  "optimizing" to `b=a` breaks too much basic Python.

Besides being more explicit (to the human reader), `copy` will be faster:

```
In [19]: timeit b=a.copy()
658 ns ± 10.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
In [20]: timeit b=a+0
2.76 µs ± 79 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```